# ubuntu 17.10 xdg-open gio-open bug? magnet url not working!

Tags: google-chrome, 17.10, deluge

It seems xdg-open, gio-open is not working with magnet link? Here's the output. It says 'ipcinterface:220 No such file: /home/yding/magnet:/?...', but it's URL not a local file.

```
yding@zbox:~$ xdg-open 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:ADBFF7EA0E936FCED6F3D088276CACC7F41D050F&dn=bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_stereo_abl.mp4&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3a80%2fannounce&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.publicbt.com%3a80%2fannounce&ws=http%3a%2f%2fdistribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net%2fvideo%2fmp4%2fbbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_stereo_abl.mp4'
This tool has been deprecated, use 'gio open' instead. See 'gio help open' for more info.
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc:30: error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/_libtorrent.py:59: RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for boost::shared_ptr already registered; second conversion method ignored. import libtorrent as lt
[ERROR ] 09:45:45 ipcinterface:220 No such file: /home/yding/magnet:/?xt=urn:btih:ADBFF7EA0E936FCED6F3D088276CACC7F41D050F&dn=bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_stereo_abl.mp4&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3a80%2fannounce&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.publicbt.com%3a80%2fannounce&ws=http%3a%2f%2fdistribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net%2fvideo%2fmp4%2fbbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_stereo_abl.mp4

yding@zbox:~$ gio open 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:ADBFF7EA0E936FCED6F3D088276CACC7F41D050F&dn=bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_stereo_abl.mp4&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3a80%2fannounce&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.publicbt.com%3a80%2fannounce&ws=http%3a%2f%2fdistribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net%2fvideo%2fmp4%2fbbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_stereo_abl.mp4' 

/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc:30: error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/_libtorrent.py:59: RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for boost::shared_ptr already registered; second conversion method ignored. import libtorrent as lt
[ERROR ] 09:46:28 ipcinterface:220 No such file: /home/yding/magnet:/?xt=urn:btih:ADBFF7EA0E936FCED6F3D088276CACC7F41D050F&dn=bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_stereo_abl.mp4&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3a80%2fannounce&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.publicbt.com%3a80%2fannounce&ws=http%3a%2f%2fdistribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net%2fvideo%2fmp4%2fbbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_stereo_abl.mp4
```

I use chrome and deluge. On previous ubuntu 17.04, clicking magnet link in chrome will launch deluge and popup a new download task. On ubuntu 17.10, doing the same thing can only launch deluge but not popup new download task. I think it's related to the error mentioned above in the output.
Use deluge-gtk with the magnet link is working. Deluge launch and new download task popup shows as expected.

```
yding@zbox:~$ deluge-gtk 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:ADBFF7EA0E936FCED6F3D088276CACC7F41D050F&dn=bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_stereo_abl.mp4&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3a80%2fannounce&tr=udp%3a%2f%2ftracker.publicbt.com%3a80%2fannounce&ws=http%3a%2f%2fdistribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net%2fvideo%2fmp4%2fbbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_stereo_abl.mp4'
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc:30: error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/_libtorrent.py:59: RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for boost::shared_ptr already registered; second conversion method ignored. import libtorrent as lt
```

Anyone encountered the same problem? Any solution?

Comment: Related: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1426299

Comment: Thank you. Here's another link. It seems the problem was fixed, but I don't know when will this patch will be taken by ubuntu 17.10. https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=779182

Answer (score 0):

For now you can manually download libglib-2.0-0 and libglib-2.0-bin for bionic (Ubuntu 18.x) and install it using dpkg to fix this problem until 17.10 updates to the newer version of libglib-2.0-0

Install this
https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libglib2.0-0

And the binaries
https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libglib2.0-bin

I ran into the same problem and install the packages above fixed the problem for me in Ubuntu 17.10