# Deluge can't open magnet links from Chrome (Ubuntu 17.10)

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-gnome, deluge

This problem occurred after upgrading from Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 to 17.10. Deluge is version 1.3.15.

When I click a magnet link in Chrome, deluge-gtk opens but it doesn't add the link or start downloading. There's lots of solutions around for older versions, but none of them work for me.

If I run `gvfs-mime --set x-scheme-handler/magnet deluge.desktop` I get:

```
This tool has been deprecated, use 'gio mime' instead.
See 'gio help mime' for more info.

gio: Unknown option --set
```

So then if I try `gio mime x-scheme-handler/magnet deluge.desktop` it tells me:

```
Set deluge.desktop as the default for x-scheme-handler/magnet
```

I also tried running `xdg-mime default deluge.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet`.

When I use `xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/magnet` it shows `deluge.desktop` as expected.

In `/usr/share/applications` I have a `deluge.desktop` file, and I think these are the relevant lines:

```
TryExec=deluge-gtk
Exec=deluge-gtk %U
MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;x-scheme-handler/magnet;
```

In `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` I have:

```
x-scheme-handler/magnet=deluge.desktop
```

in the `[Default Applications]` section.

I also tried reinstalling deluge - and now I'm out of ideas.

Thanks in advance for any help or pointers!

Comment: And naturally after posting I find a duplicate question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/971116/ubuntu-17-10-xdg-open-gio-open-bug-magnet-url-not-working ... seems to be a bug (see https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=779182 )

Answer (score 0):

I just has the same problem with Deluge and Chrome and I managed to find the proper solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307901/how-do-i-assign-magnet-links-to-use-qbittorrent):

First checking defaults:

```
$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/magnet
eiskaltdcpp-gtk.desktop
$ gvfs-mime --query x-scheme-handler/magnet
Default application for 'x-scheme-handler/magnet': eiskaltdcpp-gtk.desktop
Registered applications:
    eiskaltdcpp-gtk.desktop
    transmission-gtk.desktop
    qbittorrent.desktop
    deluge.desktop
Recommended applications:
    eiskaltdcpp-gtk.desktop
    transmission-gtk.desktop
    qbittorrent.desktop
    deluge.desktop
$
```

Then setting the new defaults:

```
$ gvfs-mime --set x-scheme-handler/magnet deluge.desktop
Set deluge.desktop as the default for x-scheme-handler/magnet
$ xdg-mime default deluge.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet
```

There is also an explanation about a problem within `Deluge Packaging` [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44849/how-to-configure-chrome-to-open-magnet-urls-with-deluge).

Comment: Thanks, but when I run "gvfs-mime --query x-scheme-handler/magnet" I get "This tool has been deprecated, use 'gio mime' instead." ... "gio: Unknown option --query"

Comment: So did you have a look at the GIO Command Line Manual ?
`https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio.html`
and see for yourself `gio mime MIMETYPE [HANDLER]` it should provide the same thing  as `gvfs-mime`.  FYI I am using Xenail 16.04.
`If no handler is given, the mime command lists the registered and recommended applications for the mimetype. If a handler is given, it is set as the default handler for the mimetype.
Handlers must be specified by their desktop file name, including the extension. Example: org.gnome.gedit.desktop.`

Comment: Yep, and GIO claims that deluge.desktop is the handler for magnet links